# webflux lots of boundedElastic-evictor TIMED_WAITING

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I send request to webflux demo server. use springboot version 2.4.1 ,I can not find reason why create so many boundedElastic-evictor thread and always keep timed waiting status.

```
ab -n 10000 -c 1000 -T "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -p test.txt http://127.0.0.1:8080/router/rest/1
```

controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/router/rest")
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping("1")
    public Mono<String> mono(){
        return Mono.just("111");
    }
}
```

webflux lots of boundedElastic-evictor TIMED_WAITING make memory up obvious.

```
"boundedElastic-evictor-9998" #10042 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=130.64s tid=0x0000023b82f71dc0 nid=0xe694 waiting on condition  [0x0000008cf91fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@15.0.1/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000070aba6988> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@15.0.1/LockSupport.java:252)
```

Comment: I have same problem.. and this starts with updating spring boot from 2.3.6 to 2.4+

Comment: this is a bug,I have comfired at [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26263)